# How to output text from the Database in InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to ask a question how to output data from the database to the button, I need to output the name of the processor, it turned out to do so in the form of text, but I can't attach how to insert the mind into the button

```
    elif call.data == "own1": 
      reply_markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) 
      for value in cur.execute("SELECT name FROM Processor where category_g='gaming';"):
            item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=value, callback_data= value) 
            reply_markup1.add(item)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, value, reply_markup=reply_markup1)
```

Where is my mistake?

I managed to get the processor name from the database in the form of text and everything worked out, but I can't do it in the form of a button